# Can you set a asp.net web user control property using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Can you set a asp.net web user control property using jQuery

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. It's possible to set the property after the page is rendered and having the property value available at a post back. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, since the controls' properties are evaluated before the PreRender phase. Every property setting made by jQuery happens after the page is rendered so it's useless.